# How to disable code completion in the Cloud9 HTML editor

Tags: cloud9

I use the Amazon Cloud9 HTML editor.
I would like to disable the code completion feature, but do not know how.

(The reason is that I just personally feel that it is more efficient for me to code if it is disabled.)

I thought [Preferences] -> [User Settings] -> [Complete As You Type], [Complete On Enter] were the settings, but I guess not.